# Error: Entry point doesn't contain a main function

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, entry-point

I am new to android studio and flutter. When I try to run my flutter program on android studio, I see a pop up which says
**Error: Entrypoint doesn't contain a main function** which I do not know the meaning of.
The Dart entrypoint is set as the main file for my program and the rest is left empty.
When I again click on run after that, I see **Configuration is still incorrect. Do you want to edit it again?** Then it says **Entrypoint doesn't contain a main function**

Could anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem is because you dont have the function main inside main.dart.
Normally, inside the **lib** folder you should have something like:

> void main() => runApp(MyApp());

Comment: Okay, I'll fix that, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

USe main() method to run your app

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
```